# MySQL sub select and return multiple records from the sub select table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I don't know if this is possible, but can mysql do a sub select and retrieve multiple records?

Here is my simplified query:

```
SELECT table1.*, 
(
SELECT      table2.*
FROM        Table2 table2
WHERE       table2.key_id = table1.key_id   
)
FROM Table1 table1
```

Basically, Table2 has X amount of records that I need to pull back in the query and I don't want to have to run a secondary query (for instance get the results from Table1 and then loop over those results and then get all the results from Table2).

Thanks.

Comment: You put it in `FROM` clause, not `SELECT`.

Comment: Why not just `JOIN` it???

Answer (score 2):

No.  The subquery in the `SELECT` clause is called a *scalar subquery*.  A scalar subquery has two important properties:

- It can only retrieve one column.
- It can only retrieve zero or one rows.

A scalar subquery -- as its name implies -- substitutes for a scalar value in an expression.  If the subquery returns no rows, the value used in the expression is `NULL`.

In your case, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON t2.key_id = t1.keyid;
```

Note that table aliases are a good thing.  However, they should make the query simpler, so repeating the table name is not a big win.

Comment: @LargeTuna . . . The `left join` should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can do a subquery that returns multiple rows or multiple columns, but it's not valid to do that in a scalar context.

You're putting a subquery in a scalar context. In other words, in the select-list, a subquery must return one column and one row (or zero rows), because it will be used for one item on the respective row as it uses the select-list to build a result.